# Magento - How to create a getChildHtml block and call it in another

Tags: magento, templates, layout

Currently i'm working to redesign a custom Magento template.

I'm facing the following problem.

In file called: 2columns-left.phtml i am facing code like this several times:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
```

These code lines makes me think that they are calling blocks and the content in them by getting the name of .phtml file.

So i have file called `slider_layred_nav.phtml` and i want to call all the content in it in file `2columns-left.phtml` so i tried this code:

So in file `2columns-left.phtml` i put:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('slider_layred_nav') ?>
```

But it is just not displaying anything.

I assume that i have to do something with the `layout` but i have no idea what.

Can you help me our resolve this mystery ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I guess you have some problem understanding the magento layouts and how the blocks are rendered in the template files.

In simple words,`getChildHtml()` renders all the blocks inside that particular block i.e child blocks of that parent block.If you use `getChildHtml('slider_layred_nav')` than it will render the block named **slider_layred_nav** not the template file.

Here **$this** has it own meaning. It refers to the block which has template file `2columns-left.phtml`.
At first you have to create a block inside the block which use the template `2columns-left.phtml`

For example:

```
<block type="core/template" name="slider_layred_nav" template="something/slider_layred_nav.phtml"/>
```

After creating this block inside the block that uses the template `2columns-left.phtml` you can do `echo $this->getChildHtml('slider_layred_nav');` to display that block inside your 2columns-left.phtml file.

Hope i made you clear to some extent.

Answer (score 0):

You are indeed missing the layout part.

If you open up page.xml (under layout folder of your theme), you can find the definition of the block **global_messages** like so :

```
<block type="core/messages" name="global_messages" as="global_messages"/>
```

But don't take that block as example, since it is a special one which does not have a template associated with it.

The cleaner way to make what you want is like so :

Create a **local.xml** file under your in app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/layout (*nota*: your_package & your_theme will vary).
Then paste this one in the new **local.xml** file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0"><!-- everything goes in here -->
  <default>
    <block type="core/template" name="slider_layred_nav" template="path/to/slider_layred_nav.phtml"/>
  </default>
</layout>
```

**path/to/slider_layred_nav.phtml** being the path to your phtml from app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/template/

**slider_layred_nav** in the *name* attribute of the block being the name passed as parameter when you are calling `$this->getChildHtml('some_name')`.